# Designing DFA to accept language of even length beginning with 11

Tags: finite-automata, dfa

Design a DFA to accept language L={w|w is of even length and begins with 11} where inputs are 0'a and 1's?

Comment: People don't like when you post a question that shows no indication that you attempted to solve it yourself, or fails to point to a specific problem you're having in solving the problem.  They are inclined to think you are just asking them to do your homework for you.  You should improve the question and touch on these issues or your question might get down voted or removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this DFA will work with even no of length and starting with 01 string.

[image]